# Grid bootstrap ficando desalinhado em painel com resultados trazidos do banco

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Estou exibindo o resultado de uma consulta em painéis, só que eles estão ficando desalinhados, quero que mostre como ta na imagem abaixo só que 1 debaixo do outro, da forma que esta, esta gerando um efeito piramide, segue código e imagem de exemplo:

```
 <div class="container">
 <?php
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_chamados)) {

        $var_chamado   = $row['CHAMADO'];
        $var_problema  = $row['PROBLEMA'];
        $var_descricao = $row['DESCRICAO'];
        $var_contato   = $row['CONTATO'];
        $var_telefone  = $row['TELEFONE'];
        $var_abertura  = $row['DATA_DE_ABERTURA'];
        $var_horasemab = $row['HORAS_EM_ABERTO'];
        $var_numloja   = $row['NUM_LOJA'];
        $var_area      = $row['AREA'];
        $var_setor     = $row['SETOR'];
        $var_tecnico   = $row['TECNICO'];
        $var_abertopor = $row['ABERTO_POR'];
        $var_status    = $row['STATUS'];
        $var_painel    = $row['PAINEL'];




echo"
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4'>
    <div class='panel panel-danger'>
      <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h3 class='panel-title'>
          <h3>
              <font  color='#FFFFFF'>
               <a class='Modal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$var_chamado
              </font>";
              if( $var_painel == 1){
              echo"<a href='ciente.php?id=". $row['CHAMADO'] ."' class='EstouCiente'>CIENTE</a>";
                }

              echo"</h3>
        </h3>
      </div>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          <h5>
             ABERTO A 0$var_horasemab HORAS <br />
             TELEFONE : $var_telefone       <br />
             ABERTO POR: $var_abertopor     <br />
             LOJA: 0$var_numloja            <br />
          </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>";
     }
  echo"</div>";
 ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

@Gabriel Sousa

```
echo"
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4'>
    <div class='panel panel-danger'>
     <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h3 class='panel-title'>    
         <a href='informacao.php?id=". $row['CHAMADO'] ."' class='left'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' aria-hidden='true'>
          </span>
         </a>";
if( $var_painel == 0){
  echo"<a href='ciente.php?id=". $row['CHAMADO'] ."' class='right'>CIENTE
        </a>";
    }
 echo" 
</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='panel-body'>
         <center>
           $var_chamado
         </center>
       </div>
    </div>        
  </div>";
    }
echo"</div>";
 ?>
```

@Matheus Godoi

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_chamados)) : ?>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-4">

  <div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

  </div>
</div>

</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o bootstrep usa um sistema de grid que uma linha (row) pode ter ate 12 colunas.

qualdo você dola o loop while

ele gera um numero x de quadrados dentro de uma row

cada quadrado usa coluna usa 4 espaços da row

sendo assim se o while imprimir mais de 3 row exede o valor limite suportado por uma row

tem que se gerar uma logica para a cada 3 quadrados gerados ele feixe a row antiga e abra uma nova

o código fica rial mais ou menos assim

```
<?php 
        $i = 0;
        $row = 0; // contador de quadrados inseridos na row
    ?>

        <div class="row">
        <?php while($i < 20) : ?>

        <?php
           if($row == 3){ 
// se dois quadrador for adicionado fecha a row e abre uma nova
                 echo '</div><div class="row"> ';
// como a row é nova o marcador zera
                 $row = 0;
               } ?>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="panel panel-danger">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>     

        <?php

        $row++; // incrementa 1 pois um quadrado foi adicionado a row
        $i++;

        endwhile; ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, perfeito , Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes

Semanticamente o HTML esta errado

```
<h3 class='panel-title'>
          <h3>
              <font  color='#FFFFFF'>
               <a class='Modal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$var_chamado
              </font>";
              if( $var_painel == 1){
              echo"<a href='ciente.php?id=". $row['CHAMADO'] ."' class='EstouCiente'>CIENTE</a>";
                }

              echo"</h3>
        </h3>
      </div>
```

Tem um h3 dentro de outro h3

pode parecer que não mas isso influencia na forma que o navegador vai renderizar isso na tela.

Outra coisa é o color

```
<font  color='#FFFFFF'>
```

No HTML5 deve ser estilizado por CSS esta forma esta obsoleta.

Tenta arrumar o código sem o PHP primeiro, se não complica mesmo,

depois vê se tem error usando este site https://validator.w3.org

por ultimo coloca o PHP.

Tentei organizar já so o HTML

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4'>
    <div class='panel panel-danger'>
      <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h3 class='panel-title'>
            <font  color='#FFFFFF'>
                   <a class='Modal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                   </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </font>              
              <a href="" class='EstouCiente'>CIENTE</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class='panel-body'>
          <h5>
             ABERTO A 0$var_horasemab HORAS <br />
             TELEFONE : $var_telefone       <br />
             ABERTO POR: $var_abertopor     <br />
             LOJA: 0$var_numloja            <br />
          </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta e incluir uma nova edição, limpando ao máximo o codigo, mais o problema persiste, teria mais alguma dica ? ; Veja a edição que coloquei abaixo de seu nome

Comment: O `<div class="row">` precisa ficar fora do `<?php while` caso contrário, a cada novo loop, será criada uma nova row e não é bem isso que queremos.

Comment: Confere se no código todas as `div` estão sendo fechadas. Removi a `div` de fechamento da div de classe col-xs-4 e tudo funcionou direitinho.

Olha: https://jsfiddle.net/matheusasdev/ga3j3wjz/

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se não há nenhum `text-align: center` no seu css.

Uma dica: tente corrigir esse `echo` do PHP. Ao invés de tratar o HTML como uma string simples, use desta forma:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_chamados)) : ?>

 //código HTML

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Obs: Posso estar enaganado (uma vez que eu não conheço todo o contexto do seu projeto) mas como você já está usando o mysql_fetch_array, não é necessário ficar criando variáveis e atribuindo a elas os valores de $row;

Comment: Veja nova edição, fiz como você disse mais ainda continua errado.