# Grupo de imagens em gird do bootstrap ficando fora do loop

Tags: php, imagem, bootstrap-3, loop, grid

Tenho uma lista de imagens onde estou usando em grid pra organiza-las ficando a quantidade exata que preciso por linhas.
Com isso eu fiz um loop para controlar os grids e tenho também o loop das imagens.

Duvida: O que poderia esta fazendo para corrigir porque os grids e as imagens estão ficando separados, como podem ver em:  `view-source google chrome`

Caso queiram ver mais sobre o grid, eu peguei desse post: [Grid bootstrap ficando desalinhado em painel com resultados trazidos do banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173039/grid-bootstrap-ficando-desalinhado-em-painel-com-resultados-trazidos-do-banco)

E como podem ver também na imagem abaixo, esse erro faz minhas imagens ficarem uma debaixo da outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> php:

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">
      <?php 
      $i = 0;
      $row = 0; 
      while($i < $count) : 
        if($row == 6){ 
         echo '</div><div class="row"> ';
         $row = 0;
       } 
       ?>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
          <?php
          $nofoto = '../../images/nofoto.jpg';
          while($rowDadosFoto = $queryDadosFoto->fetch()) {
            $foto = $rowDadosFoto['FOTO'];
            if($foto >= 1){
              echo"<li id='image_li_".$rowDadosFoto['COD_PRODUTO']."' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/".$rowDadosFoto['FOTO']."' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li>"; 
            }else{
              echo"<li id='image_li_".$rowDadosFoto['COD_PRODUTO']."' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='$nofoto' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li>"; 
            }
          }
          ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        $row++; 
        $i++;
      endwhile; 
      ?>
    </div>     
  </div>
```

> view-source google chrome

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
          <li id='image_li_4444' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/4444.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_22233' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/nofoto.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_3333' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/3333.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_5555' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/5555.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_123456' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/123456.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_1111' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/1111.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_364526' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/364526.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_7777' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/7777.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li><li id='image_li_2222' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/2222.jpg' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li>        </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>
        </div><div class="row">        
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>
            </div>     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo toda iteração dentro de um col-md-2, por isso as imagens ficam todas numa coluna e fica um monte de coluna sobrando como se vê no final:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>
        </div><div class="row">        
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                  </ul>
            </div>
```

Se for uma imagem por coluna, vc não precisa de uma ul. Não entendi como ficaria seu design mas tentei fazer algo parecido.

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">
        <?php while($rowDadosFoto = $queryDadosFoto->fetch()) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
                    <img src='../../images/<?= $rowDadosFoto['FOTO'] >= 1 ? 'produtos/'.$rowDadosFoto['FOTO'] : 'nofoto.jpg' ; ?>' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: você consegue fazer isso usando uma col mesmo e com o [drag e drop do HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp). E o codigo deu certo?

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando um fechamendo de div em baixo da `</ul>`

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row">
      <?php 
      $i = 0;
      $row = 0; 
      while($i < $count) : 
        if($row == 6){ 
         echo '</div><div class="row"> ';
         $row = 0;
       } 
       ?>

       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
          <?php
          $nofoto = '../../images/nofoto.jpg';
          while($rowDadosFoto = $queryDadosFoto->fetch()) {
            $foto = $rowDadosFoto['FOTO'];
            if($foto >= 1){
              echo"<li id='image_li_".$rowDadosFoto['COD_PRODUTO']."' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='../../images/produtos/".$rowDadosFoto['FOTO']."' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li>"; 
            }else{
              echo"<li id='image_li_".$rowDadosFoto['COD_PRODUTO']."' 
              class='ui-sortable-handle'>
              <a href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:none;' class='image_link'>
              <img src='$nofoto' class='img-responsive' style='vertical-align: middle;width:100px;height:100px;'>
              </a>
              </li>"; 
            }
          }
          ?>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
        $row++; 
        $i++;
      endwhile; 
      ?>
    </div>     
  </div>
```